# MATLAB: how can I generate 2 random numbers which sum is less than 1?

Tags: matlab, random, numbers

Does anybody know how to generate two random numbers which sum is less than one?

I found only topics describing how to generate 2 random numbers which add up to 1 (trough normalization)

Comment: The obvious solution would be to normalize them to anything less than one. Do you want to achieve a certain distribution or do you want your numbers to have certain properties?

Comment: I see now that the condition is "sum _less than_", not "sum _equal to_". So I'm retracting my duplicate-question vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Generate the first random number, r1.
2. Generate a random number less than 1 to be the random sum.
3. Define r2 as (sum - r1).

Comment: I suppose you would need to generate sum first, and then make sure r1 is generated less than sum. (Or generate sum to be larger than r1) otherwise you could have `r1=0.8, sum=0.4, r3=-0.4` which I expect to be undesirable.

Comment: I wondered that too, but original post put no bounds on the two numbers...only on their sum.

Comment: Your answer is indeed correct, but in this case I would recommend you to mention the assumption that negative numbers are allowed. That may help the asker even more!

Comment: Sorry if I bother you again... How I can do if I want to generate a third variable which squared value is less than the product of the first two variables? In practice what I'm trying to do is to generate a positive-definite 2x2 matrix...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't care too much about the distribution:

```
x = rand(2,1);
if sum(x)>1
   x=x/2;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying [normKrumpe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21306269/296974), I'd suggest

1. Generate the sum as a random number.
2. Generate a random number `r1` less than (or <=?) the sum.
3. `r2 = sum-r1`.